# Common class for network calls in Android

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to write a class for an existing project where all network calls (including Webview) can be 'controlled'. 
Basically want to force use HTTPS for all kinds of network calls or to the worst case, block all HTTP calls.

I found some solutions for API level above 23, but still trying to figure out for lower levels.

Some of the approach I found for API level 23 and above were adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="false" or networkSecurityConfig in AndroidManifest.

But these will not work in API level below 23, Any suggestions or recommendations for solving this?

Thanks in Advance and Happy coding

Comment: https://koz.io/android-m-and-the-war-on-cleartext-traffic/

Comment: @Kirguduck thanks for your comments, but detectCleartextNetwork() again was added in 23, this may not work in lower levels, right?